# Any way to test how much of my site is HTML5 supportive?

Tags: html

html5test.com displays how much your browser supports HTML5. I am recently started changing my site to HTML5 with new elements like article etc. I want to test my site in terms of may be percentage (or) wat are the elements that are old or needs to be updated?

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.modernizr.com and http://yepnopejs.com/ which help you detect browser support for css3 features and html5 features.

Also check out the html5boilerplate

Modinizr will add classes to your html tag, for instance if the user doesn't have javascript enabled the class no-js will be added so you can use .no-js in your stylesheets.

```
<html class="js flexbox canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths" lang="en">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response..i know about boiler plate, modernizer and initialiser..problem is i have already a site which i wanna convert to HTML5 as much as possible...but wat is outdated in my code CSS or HTML is something i wanna know...